# Moving external scripts to wordpress footer

Tags: php, wordpress, footer

I have some external scripts in my "wordpess head" like this:-

> //blueimp.github.io/Gallery/js/jquery.blueimp-gallery.min.js
>   or 
>   https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/masonry/3.3.0/masonry.pkgd.min.js

I want to move these scripts to my wordpress Footer. I know that these can be done via

```
function dequeue_my_scripts()  and function enqueue_scripts_to_footer()
```

to use these functions i need a Script Handle. Has anybody an idea how i can move these external scripts?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

If you load your scripts with `wp_enqueue_script` function, you can provide parameter (the last parameter in enqueue function), which tells WP to enqueue script directly to the footer of the site. Something like this:

```
add_action( 'wp_enqueue_scripts', 'my_scripts' );
function my_scripts() {
   //this script will be included in the WP foother because of the last `true` parameter
   wp_enqueue_script('masonry', 'https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/masonry/3.3.0/masonry.pkgd.min.js', [], '3.3.0', true)
}
```